# Remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

My work computer is running on Windows 7 Ultimate, and my home laptop is running on Windows 7 Home Premium.

I want to connect my work computer from my home laptop, but whenever I try to do it gives me an error message saying:

> Remote desktop can't connect to the computer for one of the following reasons 
>   
>   1. Remote access to the server is not enabled. 
>   2. The remote computer is turn off. 
>   3. The remote computer is not available in the network.

But when I tried to connect from my colleague's desktop I can connect to my computer.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check your firewall.The Remote Desktop port might be blocked by a firewall, make sure the port for Remote Desktop (usually 3389) is open.

Answer (score 0):

Do a port scan on your work computer's [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) using http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/ and check whether port 3389 is accessible. If not, ask your network administrator to open up this port.

Also make sure this port is open in both computers' firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that need to be done to get this to work. I will go through these, but there are easier ways.

1. Check that you can conect to your home IP address - Some [ISPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) do not give public IP addresses to non-commerial customers. If you google "what's my IP" from your home laptop it will give you the IP address of the router from your ISP. Then from outside your network try to ping your IP address and do a [tracert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) to make sure it's you. If you can not get access to your router, the easiest way to get around this is to use a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) I recommend, [LogmeIN](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx).
2. [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) Forward - Now you can connect to your home network. You will have to forward the incoming PORT 3389 calls to your laptop. So make the laptops IP address static, then set up a NAT forward to your assigned IP address on the router. NB: all routers are different and you will need to find how to do this on your router.
3. Now put the VPN client on your computer, connect to your home network, and start your [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) session.

There is quite a lot to do to set this up. You could also use [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) as well, like [ThinVNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/thinvnc/), but this will also require you to do steps 1 and 2. The easiest way to do this is to use a hosted VNC like [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer).